# How to add Arrays to Strings without flattening them in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, flatten

I want to do something like this :

`[1,[2],[3,4]] + " is a Nested Array." 
       => "[1,[2],[3,4]] is a Nested Array."`

But,
  `console.log([1,[2],[3,4]] + " is a Nested Array.");`
gives `1,2,3,4 is a Nested Array.`

I can do that with single dimensional array by adding square brackets in the string and letting the array to be flattened:

```
 "["+ [1,2,3,4,5] + "] is a single dimensional array." 
      => "[1,2,3,4,5] is a single dimensional array."
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify([1,[2],[3,4]]) + " is a Nested Array.");
```

Comment: Hey I don't think It's worthy to ask another question but with objects, so how can we do the same with objects??

Comment: same way `JSON.stringify()`